# Efficiently generating all possible permutations of a linked list?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, complexity-theory, permutation

There are many algorithms for generating all possible permutations of a given set of values.  Typically, those values are represented as an array, which has O(1) random access.

Suppose, however, that the elements to permute are represented as a doubly-linked list.  In this case, you cannot randomly access elements in the list in O(1) time, so many permutation algorithms will experience an unnecessary slowdown.

Is there an algorithm for generating all possible permutations of a linked list with as little time and space overhead as possible?

Comment: in fact the typical algorithm for generating all permutations will work just fine.

Comment: @izomorphius since linked list access is O(n) it might be slower by some orders of magnitude.

Comment: The algo for generating all permutations has O(1) amorthized complexity, not for each next permutation call. I will try to add an answer.

Comment: An idea might be to create an array of pointers to nodes of the linked list. taking O(n) time. Then use a permutation algorithm on that array would yield an improved time complexity.

Comment: @izomorphius- you may be right, but the measured complexity of these algorithms usually assumes an array representation.  The fact that it's amortized O(1) per permutation isn't meaningful if random access is required.

Comment: I would try to benchmark std::next_pemutation on list. I would bet it will not perform significantly worse than on vector.

Comment: Creating an array out of the linked list as pre-processing and then use the "black box" algorithm for array will have negligible overhead, given the computational complexity of generating all possible permutations.

Comment: @amit- O(n) space overhead is quite a lot.  I was hoping for an O(1) or O(log n)-space overhead if at all possible.

Comment: The SOP method is a recursive routine that always does swaps of adjacent members.  It will work the same with an array or a list, regardless.

Comment: @svick- The time and space complexities are separate.  It might take a long time to generate permutations, but if I can avoid using unnecessary space that would be great.

Comment: @templatetypedef I disagree the claim it is quite a lot, given the fact that if you have more then 50 elements your algorithm will practically never finish running (before the extinction of mankind). Moreover, generating the permutations itself is `O(n)` space (you need to output it somehow)

Comment: @amit- How does generating permutations use O(n) space?  If you permute the linked-list in-place, wouldn't it only take O(1) space?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of the recursive approach to generate permutations actually (not in place and requires stack trace). Nevertheless, when talking about `n!` different permutations, space of `n` references should not be an issue for any practical reason. (If the question is purely theoretical, [cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) should be better for it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to think of how **you** generate all permutations on a piece of paper.

You start from the rightmost number and go one position to the left until you see a number that is smaller than its neighbour. Than you place there the number that is next in value, and order all the remaining numbers in increasing order after it. Do this until there is nothing more to do. Put a little thought in it and you can order the numbers in linear time with respect to their number.

This in fact is the typical algorithm used for next permutation as far as I know. I see no reason why this would be faster on array than on list.

Comment: Is there a academic/known name for the implementation you are describing ?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm).  It generates all permutations of a sequence only by swapping adjacent elements; something which you can do in O(1) in a doubly linked list.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the linked-list's data into an array, which takes `O(n)` and then use Heap's permutation ( http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/numbers/permutation) to find all the permutations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Factoradic Permutation Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations), and rearrange the node pointers accordingly to generate the resulting permutation in place without recursion.

A pseudo description:

```
element_to_permute = list
temp_list = new empty list
for i = 1 in n! 
   indexes[] = factoradic(i)
   for j in indexes[]
      rearrange pointers of node `indexes[j]` of `element_to_permute` in `temp_list`
```